# How to display random and distinct images on display onclick

Tags: image, button, random, distinct, android-image

I am developing a game similar to geochallenge game in facebook.  here i am unable to decide whether i should use Image buttons/Grid view/Image view or some other else....?
please can any one suggest in this regard...

My requirement is 
                  I should store some number of images.  And at particular time I should randomly display three distinct images, and these images will be replaced by other images when any of those images is clicked. The the images should not be repeated.
can you help me please.

Now i am using Image button concept but the images are repeating in three image buttons.  But i should get distinct images on  each image button.

Answer (score 0):

after a long struggle I was able to get a solution. Here's what I did.

I have a flags array "Country[]" and three Image Buttons declared as `ImageButton array bt[]={id1,id2,id3};`, which I use with the following code:

```
public void randomDisplay()
{
    L=Country.length;

    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        int random=rand.nextInt(L-1);

        if(i==0)
            id1=Country[random];
        if(i==1)
            id2=Country[random];
        if(i==2)
            id3=Country[random];

        id=getResources().getIdentifier(Country[random], "drawable", getPackageName());
        bt[i].setImageResource(id);

        String temp=Country[L-1];
        Country[L-1]=Country[random];
        Country[random]=temp;

        L=L-1;
    }
}
```

The above code will shift one country name to the end of the country array at each repetition, and decrements the country array length.  This will avoid the duplicate names on ImageButtons.  If you have any question please let me know...